# JSON conversion error?

Tags: android, json

I am using `socket.io` to connect with Node.js. The data is sent successfully so everything is working fine but while fetching data, it shows an error. It just says error about JSON conversion. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket mSocket;
    TextView textView,getmessage;
    String message;

    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.201.1:8085");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mSocket.on("message", onMessage);
        mSocket.connect();
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    try {
                        message = data.getString("message");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                    getmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get);
                    getmessage.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }
    };


        public void load(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "you clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSocket.connect();
            //new BackgroundTask().execute();
        }

        public void send(View view) {
            String message = textView.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSocket.emit("message", message);
        }
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-16 21:42:41.843 16958-16958/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shuresnepali.mobiletolocalhostconnection, PID: 16958
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
   at com.example.shuresnepali.mobiletolocalhostconnection.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:59)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject` which means that `arg[0]` is a string and not a `JSONObject`. Maybe you need to parse it?

Comment: Can you post your response as well.?

Comment: i guess you need `JSONObject data = new JSONObject((String)args[0]);`

Comment: Thank you #Pavneet_Singh for your kind reply ...but it didn't work at all..it shows some error regarding to this error org.json.JSONException: Value back of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: just Log value of `args[0]` and post it here

Comment: hi there, using Log.e("error",String.valueOf(args[0])); it showed the exact message that the node.js is sending but i am not able to use is directly like getmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get); and  getmessage.setText(String.valueOf(args[0]));

Comment: You can try to use a JSON validator to make sure that your string is correct. Grab the string and paste it into https://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There code snippet doesn't show enough info.

it may be your line:
message = data.getString("message");

is message a String type? where are you declaring it?
if it isn't, try declaring it as a string, then call:
getmessage.setText(message);

Answer (score 0):

Yours args[0] is a String. You cannot directly cast a String to JSONObject.

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
```

Instead you should rather

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(args[0]);
```

This is with the assumption that you are indeed getting a json response